# can't find the option to international fonts

Tags: interface, text-object, windows, system, font

i use files with other languages than English, i used to check international fonts option to let blender display them correctly, now i can't find the option or any documentation about it, any help is appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Language</kbd> setting is under <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> on the <kbd>Interface</kbd> tab.

[image]

Comment: hi, yes i pointed out the location of the setting as of 3.6, it doesn't have the international font option present! how to make other languages show correctly?

Comment: Ah ok. I can only find one mention of that option from a Google [search](https://blenderartists.org/t/where-is-the-international-fonts-option-in-blender-2-8/1197381) and it looks as if it was removed after Blender 3.79! No wonder I didn't understand your question! I can't help in that case I'm afraid.

Comment: According to another [posting](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/58608) I've just found it was renamed to "Translate UI" but I've no idea where you find that option now.

Comment: ..and it looks as if there's a built-in [addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/system/ui_translations.html#manage-ui-translations) for that nowadays. Search for 'Manage' under Edit> Preferences > Addons.

Comment: tried that add-on, same result, the file names are displayed incorrectly.

Comment: No idea in that case. Report it as a bug maybe? Help > Report a Bug in Blender.